# Is there exists a soluble maximal subgroup in multiplicative group of quaternions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that $H_{\mathbb R}$ is ordinary quaternion over $\mathbb R$, we know that 
$\mathbb C^* \cup\mathbb C^*j $ is a soluble maximal subgroup of  ${H_{\mathbb R}}^*$.
Now, consider that $H_{\mathbb Q}$ is ordinary quaternion over $\mathbb Q$. can we find a soluble maximal subgroup in  ${H_{\mathbb Q}}^*$?